# Restrict Access to the JSON URL within Drupal from the App

Tags: json, drupal, restrict

I am working in Drupal which generates JSON that can be assessed through a URL. The URL in turn is parsed by the app (made in Titanium) to show data.

Now the problem is that this URL can be publicly assessed by anyone too and one can see all the details. The app, on the other hand, shows the same data to the restrictive users.

My question is that how can I restrict anyone who opens the URL through a browser whilst allowing the app to assess the data through the same URL?

The URL looks like this:-

```
http://site.com/section/allowed-users-in-the-list.json
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: You should add permissions to that path either using hook_menu or hook_menu_alter

Answer (score 0):

look into $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] this will tell you where the script is coming from. You can do a validation there too.